# Why does null React component state initialization get `never` type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

When initializing a component's state to `null` outside of the component's constructor, the state has the type `never` in the render function.

However, when the state is initialized in the constructor, the state has the correct type.

According to most questions on StackOverflow about the two ways to initialize state (in babeled JS), these two methods should be equivalent. However, in Typescript, they are not. Is this a bug or the intended behavior?

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";

interface Person {
  name: string;
  address: string;
}
interface Props {
  items: Person[];
}
interface State {
  selected: Person | null;
}

class PersonSelector extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  // DOES NOT WORK:
  state = {
    selected: null
  };

  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
    // WORKS:
    // this.state = {
    //   selected: null
    // };
  }

  handleClick = (item: Person) => {
    this.setState({
      selected: item
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { selected } = this.state;
    let selectedLabel = <div>None selected</div>;
    if (selected) {
      selectedLabel = <div>You selected {selected.name}</div>;
    }
    return (
      <div>
        {selectedLabel}
        <hr />
        {this.props.items.map(item => (
          <div onClick={() => this.handleClick(item)}>{item.name}</div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const people: Person[] = [
  { name: "asdf", address: "asdf asdf" },
  { name: "asdf2", address: "asdf asdf2" }
];

document.write('<div id="root"></div>');
ReactDOM.render(
  <PersonSelector items={people} />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Here is the sample code on CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/10l73o4o9q

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> According to most questions on StackOverflow about the two ways to
>   initialize state (in babeled JS), these two methods should be
>   equivalent. However, in Typescript, they are not.

They are different in TypeScript because assigning `state` in the class body (not in the constructor) declares `state` in `PersonSelector`, overriding the declaration in base class `React.Component`. In TypeScript, overriding declaration is allowed to have different, more strict type, one-way compatible with the type of the same property in the base class.

When initialized without type annotation, this type is determined from the type of the value:

```
class PersonSelector extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  // DOES NOT WORK:
  state = {
    selected: null
  };
```

You can see that type of the `state` is `{selected: null}`, as expected. It becomes `never` in this code

```
const { selected } = this.state;
let selectedLabel = <div>None selected</div>;
if (selected) {
```

because inside `if` statement, the type of `selected` is narrowed, using the information that `selected` is `true`. Null can never be true, so the type becomes [`never`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#never).

As suggested in other answer, you can annotate `State` explicitly when initializing in the class body

```
class PersonSelector extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  state: State = {
    selected: null
  };
```

**Update** to clarify how the initialization in the class body is different from assigning in the constructor

When you set `state` in the constructor

```
  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       selected: null
    };
  }
```

you are assigning the value to `state` property that already exists as it was declared in the base class. The base class is `React.Component<Props, State>`, and [`state`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/v15/index.d.ts#L322) property there is declared to have `State` type, taken from the second generic argument in `<Props, State>`.

Assignments do not change the type of the property - it remains `State`, regardless of the value assigned.

When you set `state` in the class body it's not mere assignment - it's a declaration of class property, and each declaration gives a type to the declared entity - either explicitly via type annotation, or implicitly, inferred from the initial value. This typing happens even if the property already exists in the base class. I can't find anything in the documentation that confirms this, but there is [github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10570) that describes exactly this behavior, and confirms that sometimes it goes against the developer's intent (no solution implemented in the language so far).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm still not quite sure I understand "when initialized without type annonation, this type is determined from the type of the value". Why is that not true when setting `this.state` in the constructor?

Is this due to an inherent limitation in typescript, or is it a desired behavior to be able to restrict the type of `state` with the class property?

Comment: "They are different in TypeScript because assigning state in the class body (not in the constructor) declares state in PersonSlector, overriding the declaration in base class React.Component". Is there a place in the typescript docs where I can read more about this difference?

Comment: @Eric I updated the answer. The only thing I found that confirms it is this [github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10570)

Comment: Thank you! That github issue is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 8):

You can definitely initialize the state outside of the constructor, but you need to be sure to type it so that TypeScript can reconcile the type of the initial value and the type of the generic. Try:

```
class PersonSelector extends React.Component<Props, State> {
    state: State = {
        selected: null
    };

    // ...
}
```