# Using state and includes in React gives Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never' error

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a React application in TypeScript with code that contains

```
export interface State {
    expandedRows: any,
}

class MyComponent extends React.Component<Props, State> {

    state = {
        expandedRows: [],
    };

    isExpanded = (rowId: number) => {
        return this.state.expandedRows.includes(rowId);
    }
```

and it emits the error `TypeScript error: Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.  TS2345` when I input the `rowId` variable into the `includes` method.

I tried changing the type of expandedRows to Array, but I get the same error.  I tried removing expandedRows from the State interface, and I get the same error.  I feel like perhaps my State interface is somehow now getting assigned to `this.state`.  Or perhaps the `includes` method doesn't have a type specified for its input.  How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the other good answer - you can specify the type of `state`

```
state: State = {
    expandedRows: [],
};
```

Comment: This is really the best solution, because it uses the interface that was defined above, preventing redundancy.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
state = {
    expandedRows: [] as any,
};
```

However, you might want to set the type of `expandedRows` to `number[]`, since you expect indexes in there:

```
export interface State {
    expandedRows: number[],
}
state = {
    expandedRows: [] as number[],
};
```

An sounder solution without type casting would be to initialize state in the constructor:

```
constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.state = {
      expandedRows: [],
   };
}
```

Comment: It worked!  Can you provide any explanation about what that does and why it is necessary?

Comment: I think it has to do with the fact that you're doing declaration and initialization in one shot. I couldn't find any docs to support this, but this post explains it pretty well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51201513/781090